This seems more complicated than it needs to be
I am a begginer and am trying to write something along the lines of:
Captivated by you.
I get lost in your summer smile,
and I rest in the autumn leaves of your eyes. (I am trying to say that I "rest" my gaze)
I got to this, but it seems more complicated than it needs to be. Can you help me out?
被你迷住了。我迷失在你夏日的微笑里，我停留在你眼中的秋叶里。
Neither chinese or english are my first language.

do you mean "sunny smile'?

I meant summer, to keep the seasons "theme"

醉心于你。那笑靥绚烂如夏花，令人失魂。那双眸澄澈似秋波，引人注目。 A bit more literary, a little less accuracy. Personally replacing autumn leaves by autumn ripple / 秋波, since 秋波 metaphorizes beauty's eye contact / 眼神 in Chinese.

May I ask what nationality are you? Because "lost in your summer smile, and rest in the autumn leaves of your eyes" sound "strange" even in English.

I am a native portuguese speaker

These are complicated emotions, which may not be expressed in very few words!
Captivated by you.
I get lost in your summer smile,
and I rest in the autumn leaves of your eyes.
Two similar attempts, both perhaps longer than you wish:
你让我着了迷。
我沦陷在你那如夏日般明媚的笑容中，
我停歇在你那如秋天落叶般温柔的眼眸里。
我被你迷了眼。
你那如夏日般明媚的笑容让我沦陷，
你那如秋天落叶般温柔的眼眸是我停歇的港湾。
Vive l'amour!
